# Retrieve data error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

I execute select statement

```
select 
    Orders.Oid as 'Order ID',
    Eid as 'Employee ID',
    Barcode,
    PacksQty as 'Packs Quantity',
    UnitQty as 'Units Quantity',
    Date as 'Order Date',
    Price as 'Total Price' 
from  OrderDetails 
  inner join Orders 
      on OrderDetails.Oid = Orders.Oid 
where OrderDetails.Date ='05/07/2013'
```

And it does not retrieve data and does not give me any error. And by the way, there is data in the table rows that have the specified date in Date column.

Comment: One thing to check is that the date conversion from text is doing what you expect... you may want to use a safer text representation "yyyy-mm-dd"

Answer (score 0):

Because the query isn't throwing up it means the query is executing successfully, which leaves the following possibilities:

1. You have no data in tables OrderDetails or Orders
2. You have no OrderDetails where OrderDetails.Date = '05/07/2013'

Do this to see if you have a column with that date

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DateCount FROM OrderDetails WHERE Date = '05/07/2013'
```

If this returns 0 you have no OrderDetails with that Date, if it does return 1 or more do the following

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersWithDateCount
FROM Orders 
    JOIN OrderDetails 
        ON Orders.Oid = OrderDetails.Oid
WHERE OrderDetails.Date = '05/07/2013'
```

If you return zero on the example above but don't return zero on the example below

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrderDetailsWithDateCount
FROM OrderDetails
WHERE Date = '05/07/2013'
```

you have detail records but no order records, or orphaned records. Make sure you have the correct dates, do the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date 
FROM OrderDetails 
WHERE Date BETWEEN GETDATE()-90 AND GETDATE()
```

If you see a match for your date it might be because your data type is a date time, try using

```
DECLARE @TargetDate DATE = '05/07/2013'   

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OrderDetails 
WHERE OrderDetails.Date 
    BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-1,@TargetDate) 
        AND DATEADD(day,1,@TargetDate)
```

If this does return something other then 0 then you need to use this approach to get the correct results. If it does return 0 then you definitely have no order details with a date of `'05/07/2013'`

Comment: i am sure i have a data in those tables i will take a screen shoot and show you that

Comment: @MuhammedSalah tell me the results of the queries and I will let you know what the problem is with this code

Comment: the result is retrieve data from 2 tables where 's the date time in one table of them is '05/07/2013'and the Oid is Primary key

Comment: @MuhammedSalah I mean the queries in my answer, if you tell me the info you get I can direct you towards the problem

Comment: your answer returns 0 in each situation

Comment: The Last Code Returns Me The Whole Dates that found in the table but the all previous code after it still gaves me 0

Comment: Yup Am Sure And I Get A Screen shoot for the data and i can't upload it because i still have 8 reputation

Comment: still 0 i got an idea i will try it and i will give u the feedback

Comment: I Discovered the problem and the problem is i must mention the date and time in the select statement not the date only and that 's anthore problem :s

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select Orders.Oid as 'Order ID',Eid as 'Employee ID',Barcode,PacksQty as 'Packs Quantity',
UnitQty as 'Units Quantity',Date as 'Order Date',Price as 'Total Price' from   
OrderDetails join Orders 
on OrderDetails.Oid = Orders.Oid 
Where OrderDetails.Date ='2031-07-05'
```

Comment: @MuhammedSalah You are using inner join so the Oid should be available in both tables. Please verify.

Comment: i try another statement 

    select * from OrderDetails where Date ='2013/7/5'

and the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Just try this..Use the date format as shown 
    Where OrderDetails.Date ='2031 **Jul** 05'

What is the type of OrderDetails.Date..?
Is it datetime or date..?
If its datetime change the condition as this

> WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(12),OrderDetails.Date,13)='05 Jul 2013'

Comment: Oops, I missed out the closing bracket of the convert function..I just corrected it now..

Comment: Try this.. WHERE CONVERT(CHAR(12),OrderDetails.[Date],13)='05 Jul 2013'

Comment: i get the problem finally the problem is i write the date like this '05/07/2013'and it must be like that '05-07-2013' :D Damn Its kill'in me :D